# Asp.net signal R library...I can not see my chat history and i want to chat only with 1 users me and another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, chat, signalr, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net Signal R library..and how to make i can chat with only one person not group chat is it possible with asp.net signal r library?

also i want to see chat history without saving database is it possible to broad cast chat history to particular users?

///Class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Chat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

///View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js")"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send messages to a specific user you can use the Clients.Client method, ex:

```
Clients.Client(someClientsConnectionId).foo();
```

To retrieve clients connection id's you can capture it Context.ConnectionId.  So your hub could look something like this to track users and send to them specifically.

```
public MyHub: Hub 
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
...
    public void Join(string userName)
    {
        _users[theUsersUserName] = Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public void SendToUser(string userName, string message)
    {
        Clients.Client(_users[userName]).foo(message).
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have done your way, but not working it is not any user can see chat ... i have also tried to make with Group from over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167735/signalr-net-client-how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-group but not working can you please give me working code..

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not going to write all of the code for you.  The code that I have given works 100% for sending a message Client -> Client and I've also given you enough direction to implement a working, more advanced product.  If you're having some troubles with the API of SignalR check out the documentation here: http://www.asp.net/signalr.  There's a ton of great resources.

Comment: Hi, Is there any paid chat application, because with signalR, need to make custom code? I have checked here mango chat but might be it is not supported with mvc4